# Hide NTFS compression blue double arrow icon overlay

Tags: windows-10, icons, compression

Since the last Windows 10 update I have these blue double arrows on almost every item (all files & folders that are NTFS compressed).

How can I remove these?

[image: Blue double arrow]

Comment: That the icon overlay that's showing that it's compressed (new feature in Windows 10). What do you feel needs "fixing" exactly?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 in some other view sizes they are taking a lot of space of the preview thumbnail and they are also on the icons on the taskbar (the programs where the executable is compressed) which decreases the clearity of the UI for me immensly since i have most of my drives (with and without software) compressed for space saving purposes. i also removed the blue text marker for compression and i really dislike this addition and would like to remove the double arrow/make it invisible =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the *empty.ico* file, a fully transparent icon you've put `%SystemRoot%\system32. Add this registry settings:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"179"="empty.ico,0"
```

Restart explorer.exe from the task manager, and you're done. Blue arrows are gone.

*Helper script and explanation: http://nerdshack.info/windows-10-and-double-arrow-icon-of-death/*

Comment: The linked article mentions just `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]`. What is the `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]` for?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I thought some 32-bit applications could need this. But after some experimentation, I can't find a case where it is required.

Comment: I just checked on a recently installed Windows 10 machine. There's no `Shell Icons` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`? (Oh I just found out that you can create the directory, and it should work fine).