# Is there a way to hide the blue compression arrows on a Win 10 icon

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop-icons

In Windows 10 there is a new indicator to show a folder or file is being compressed.

It even shows this for shortcuts and folders.

[image]

[image]

I don't want to see this...
How do I make them disappear (other than just turning off the file compression property for the entire drive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1004536/hide-ntfs-compression-blue-double-arrow-icon-overlay